# Does Android SDK have existing ability to forward bluetooth traffic over network?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, bluetooth, forwarding

I am writing an Android app that manages two connections: one to a paired and connected bluetooth device, and one to a TCP socket connected to a particular host/port.

It acts as a tether for the second bluetooth device. Anything it reads from the bluetooth socket it writes to the TCP socket, and anything read from the TCP socket is written to the bluetooth socket.

My question is whether there is a canonical way to do something like this. What was meant to be a simple forwarder app is quickly turning into a more complicated threaded application.

The second bluetooth device has no data connectivity, and shouldn't even realize that it's communicating through a third party. It doesn't even know the host/port needed to connect to the TCP socket